# How I Return sid1 sid2 PAIRS SQL

Tags: sql

The name of the table is `Catlog`

```
Catlog (sid, pid, cost)
```

sid,pid,cost= int

I need to return pairs of sid1 sid2  when sid1 > sid2  by cost

```
sid pid cost
1    1   555 
2    2   222
3    3   333
4    4   444

result

sid1 sid2
1      4
2      1
```

Comment: `3 2 1` are 3 columns and you want `sid1` `sid2`. Maybe you think about `3 2`, `2 1`.

Comment: what cost do you want as sort criteria? The one related to sid1 or the one related to sid2?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:
    `SELECT c1.sid AS sid1, c2.sid AS sid2 FROM Catlog c1, Catlog c2...`

But I don't have details to define the whole query (the link between c1 and c2). Please describe what is `sid` and what is `pid` (and `cost`). Which is primary key, etc.